# foreach returning the same row 4 times codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and I'm trying to populate a `<table>` and just getting the same row 4 times.
My model:

```
$sql2=
    "SELECT *
    FROM puntos
    WHERE checklist_idchecklist='$idchecklist'";
    $qry2=$this->db->query($sql2);
    $puntos=$qry2->row();
    return $puntos
```

This query returns 2 arrays of 4 attributes each, i tested it doing the SQL query on phpmyadmin.

My controller:

```
function verpuntos() {
    $this->load->model('checklistm');
    $puntos=$this->checklistm->obtenerpuntos();
    $this->load->view('plantilla/headerguardia');
    $this->load->view('checklist/lista', $puntos);
    $this->load->view('plantilla/footer');
}
```

My view:

```
$punto=array(
    'descripcion' => $descripcion,
    'lugar' => $lugar,
    'tipo' => $tipo,
    'urgencia' => $urgencia);

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Lugar</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Urgencia</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($punto as $row) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$descripcion.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$lugar.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$tipo.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$urgencia.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            } 
            ?>
        <tbody>
    </table>
```

And this is what I'm getting, the same row 4 times:
[image: And this is what I'm getting, the same row 4 times]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeigniter `row()` fetch the first row in object format.`$puntos=$qry2->row();` This statement fetch only first row of your fetched data in object fromat. SO no need to use foreach loop. Just try like this..

```
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'.$puntos->descripcion.'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$puntos->lugar.'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$puntos->tipo.'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$puntos->urgencia.'</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
```

For more see here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table">
 <tr>
 <th>Descripcion</th>
 <th>Lugar</th>
 <th>Tipo</th>
 <th>Urgencia</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <?php 
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach($punto as $row)
      {
        echo '<td>'.$row.'</td>';
      } 
      echo '</tr>';
    ?>
 </tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$punto['item_1_name'].'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$punto['item_2_name']..'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$punto['item_3_name']..'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$punto['item_4_name']..'</td>';
       echo '</tr>';
```

item_1_name = index name of array returned